# Tagging users in user feed post using graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, tagging

On the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) page it shows a table showing the arguments we can use to create a new post to a feed

- /PROFILE_ID/feed
- Publish a new post on the given profile's feed/wall
- message, picture, link, name, caption, description, source, place, tags

We want to be able to post to a users wall and tag their friends. 
i.e. User 1 is doing something with User 2 and 5 others

What format should the tag attribute take?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested:

- tags is sent as an array of FB user ids
- tags can only be added if there is a place associated with the post also

Answer (score 0):

you have to post a Checkin to add place and tag friends

Answer (score 0):

On [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) you can use the below parameters:

```
/me/feed?message=<text-message-after-encoded>&place=<page-ID-of-location>&tags=<facebook-user-id,facebook-user-id,...>
```